# Am I allowed to share Stack Overflow data along with a paper that uses it?

Tags: ethics, data

I plan on submitting a paper that uses Stack Overflow data (contents of Stack Overflow questions, fetched using the Stack Exchange API) to a conference, and the conference is welcoming authors to share the code and the data used.

I saw some other papers that use Twitter data (Tweets) only share the tweet ID instead of the tweet itself, and they said that it is due to Twitter's privacy policy.

Does Stack Overflow have such a privacy policy?

Comment: In many jurisdictions you need approval from an ERB before collecting the data since this involves data from persons. Did you do that?

Comment: This is probably better as a "meta" question. I've flagged it for mod attention.

Comment: On the [main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), there are several questions that deal with the usage of Stack Exchange data for academic papers ([here is a list of academic papers using Stack Exchange data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data)). Have a look if you can find more info there. In doubt, you can contact the Stack Exchange staff.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano, thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The license information can be found at https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/licensing, which also has links to the terms of service.

That, in turn, has links to the API terms of service.